# Manually rewind unused film to its canister

Tags: film, camera-basics, 35mm

I need an advice. Because I'm a total amateur camera-lover.
So I just tried to load a film on a point shoot camera without having any idea if the camera is working or not. I loaded it smoothly. BUT, when I tried to shoot unfortunately the shooting button can not work. I don't know what to do with that camera so I opened the back and rewind it back manually to its canister.

I only have one question,
Can I use the film in another camera? :(

Comment: Does your camera wind all of the film out of the canister immediately after you load it and then wind it back in as you shoot each frame? Or does it wind it out as you shoot each frame and then back in after it has all been exposed?

Comment: @Michael was that first procedure really so common? The only camera I ever came across that did that was the Hasselblad XPan. Oh, and disposable cameras did it too I think. Certainly didn't come across it in any cheap, reusable point and shoot

Comment: A lot of Canon's point and shoots did it, just like their EOS film cameras. It makes a lot of sense if you think about it. Which would you rather have protected if the back pops open? The frames you've already exposed (other than the last couple) or the film that has yet to be exposed?

Answer (score 4):

Any part of the film that was exposed to light after you opened the back of the camera before you wound it back in will not be useable. It will be completely exposed and when developed will be totally black, resulting in a totally white print.

Comment: and to be explicit...Any part of the film that was NOT exposed to light _will_ be usable. The next camera you load the film in, just advance past the leader that had been exposed to light in the first camera.

Comment: That depends on whether what was in the cartridge was already exposed via conventional means or unexposed when the back was opened.

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse the film, but if you opened the camera in anything other than a completely dark room to rewind it, all of that film will be exposed and unusable. When you reload the film in another camera, advance it past the point that you got to with the broken camera. And next time, do these kinds of operations in a dark room (!).

Comment: I didn't rewind it in dark room, I rewind it with indoor lighting. Actually I kinda know It will be unusable. I'm just trying to find a hope. Lol. Thank you anyway.

Comment: no hope................

Comment: ...in a dark room...or in a changing bag: http://www.bluemaize.net/im/bags/film-changing-bag-2.jpg

Comment: Anywhere it's completely dark. A room, a bag, a cave...